# QR Code scanner in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, barcode-scanner

I found some html5 qr code scanner and it works on web browser

but I don't know how to use it on IBM Worklight

Is there any way to scan qr code on Worklight

html5 + javascript is better than native code

Answer (score 0):

There are some 'native' HTML5 implementations for this. One of them is https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode which uses navigator.getUserMedia (which might not be supported on devices).

In a hybrid app (including IBM Worklight), you use this by referring the libraries as specified in the Usage guide.

If navigator.getUserMedia is not supported, then you need to use a Cordova plugin (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner) which can be integrated in a IBM WL hybrid app manually.